# How to add Signature security information in soap header

Tags: java, soap, spring-security, spring-ws

I am trying to implement Spring WS Security using Signature in both server and client side.

I have added the WSS4J interceptors in both client and server configurations.

However, I am getting an exception that states:No WS-Security header found.

I think I need to add some security information in my SOAP Request Header in my client. But since my wsdls do not have any security information, wsdlimport tool does not generate any header specific method.

I looked at this link : http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-52204.html but it does not help in resolving the issue.

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi my server config is : `<bean id="wsDigCerSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSe curityInterceptor">
<property name="validationActions" value="Signature"/>
<property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support .CryptoFactoryBean">
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
<property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/keystore.jks"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>`

Comment: My client config is: `<bean id="wsDigCerSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSe curityInterceptor">
<property name="securementActions" value="Signature"/>
<property name="securementUsername" value="MyCert"/>
<property name="securementPassword" value="123456"/>
<property name="securementSignatureCrypto">
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support .CryptoFactoryBean">
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
<property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/keystore.jks"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>`

Comment: After I this I get the No WS-Security header found error. I guess I need to add the security information to the SOAP Header, but I am not sure what to add and how? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: does keystore both have private key entry and public certificate key?

Comment: The keystore has been generated with keytool. I am not sure but I assume that it should have private key entry and public certificate key.

Comment: can you share keytool -list command results

Comment: keytool -genkeypair -alias myCert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass 123456 -keystore.jks -storepass 123456 -v -validity 1095 -dname "CN=myCert, OU=AA, O=AAA, L=AAAA, ST=Unknown, C=AAAAA"

Comment: run the command keytool -list and share the results of that command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18886/discussion-between-zaffargachal-and-sai)

Comment: @zaffargachal: Running the command keytool -list gives me an error. I am new to Spring WS, so maybe I am missing something here. Thanks

Comment: this link might be helpful for you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

Comment: Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

mycert, 1 Nov, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 1A:51:D8:D6:2C:76:6B:56:77:80:05:82:AE:F3:2B:10
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes now private key will be used by server and client need public key, so you are missing the public key, generate public key from that private key using keytool comand and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the issue of key store, Server must have keystore containing the private key and client must have keystore that contnains public key generated from the same private key.

Comment: So, I do not need any changes to be made in SOAP Header? Like adding some Handler for the Signature?

Comment: No I dont think so, when you provide private and public key pair, problem will be solved

Comment: public key generated from same private key? I thought the keytool will generate a self signed public key. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can do it by generating certificate against the private key. and import the certificate back in the store

Comment: But I have already generated the keytool using the genkeypair option. So public/private key must be generated in the store. It would be great if you can provide a sample example? Thanks